# C#: Почему программное нажатие сочетания клавиш работает не во всех окнах?

Tags: c#, winapi

Имеется код, который при нажатии определенной клавиши/сочетания клавиш прогарммно нажимает сочетание клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *(Выделить текст в строке)*.

---

**Проблема:**

Все отлично работает в *блокноте, браузере, в командной строке* и других окнах, но не работает с текстовыми полями в играх *(например, `Dota 2`, `CS:GO`)*.

То есть, когда я нажимаю <kbd>G</kbd> *(кнопка для вызова <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)* вообще ничего не происходит. При этом функция нажатия <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> вызывается, то есть клавиша <kbd>G</kbd> не перехватывается игрой.

---

**Решение на Python**

Так или иначе, например этот код на `Python` отлично работает **и в браузере и в игре**, при этом даже не перехватывая клавишу из других программ:

```py
import keyboard
keyboard.add_hotkey('G', callback=lambda: keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+a'))
keyboard.wait()
```

Насколько я знаю, он тоже ссылается к `user32.dll`, но почему он работает, а на `C#` нет - мне не понятно.

Вот исходник функции [**`keyboard.press_and_release()`**](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py) (477 строка), которая ссылается на функцию `send()`.

---

**Код:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // при нажатии на кнопку G программа нажмет CTRL+A 
            NHotkey.Wpf.HotkeyManager.Current.AddOrReplace("G", Key.G, ModifierKeys.None, (sender, e) => { PressCtrlA(sender, e); });
        }

        // метод для ожидания освобождения всех клавиш клавиатуры
        // чтобы программное нажатие CTRL+A сработало корректно
        private static readonly Key[] keys = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Key)).Cast<Key>().Where(key => key != Key.None).ToArray();
        private async Task WaitForKeysReleaseAsync()
        {
            int threshold = 0;
            while (Keyboard.Modifiers != ModifierKeys.None || keys.Any(key => Keyboard.IsKeyDown(key)))
            {
                if (threshold++ == 100) // ~5 секунд
                    throw new TimeoutException("Keyboard release timed out or stuck keys");
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        }

        // подождать пока освободится клавиатура и нажать CTRL+A
        private async void PressCtrlA(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await WaitForKeysReleaseAsync();
            KeyboardManager.PressHotkey(Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control);
        }
    }
}
```

**В коде используется класс `KeyboardManager` для программного нажатия клавиш, вот код от него: https://pastebin.com/xRtv3drq**

Также используется пакет `NHotkey.Wpf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря [**ответу**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72288515/14519908) на английской версии сайта понял в чем проблема.

Мой код нажатия клавиши фактически не нажимает клавишу, а только отправляет сообщение о том, что клавиша была нажата. Обычные окна считывают только это сообщение, в то время как игры `DirectX` требуют фактического нажатия клавиши.

В ответе мне дали список кодов клавиш, которые будут работать для игр `DirectX` и уже после этого, добавив в библиотеку `Python` `keyboard` строку, выводящую коды клавиш, я заметил, что эти коды полностью совпадают с теми, что мне дали в ответе.

В общем, это заработало для `Dota 2` и некоторых других играх, но не работало в `CS:GO`. Причина оказалась проста - нужно было поставить задержку в `20 мс` между нажатием сочетания и отпусканием. То есть не "нажать и резко отпустить", а "нажать и подождать".